# How do I find the time from a given velocities ina circular motion?

Tags: vectors, physics, kinematics

This problem has left me going in circles. No pun intended, but I'm confused at how to use the vectors given to find the time.

The problem is as follows:

> A sphere has a uniform circular motion. This object passes through two
>   points $A$ and $B$, when this happens its speed is
>   $\left(-4\hat{\textrm{i}}+4\sqrt{3}\hat{\textrm{j}}\right)\frac{m}{s}$ and $\left(8\hat{\textrm{i}}\right)\frac{m}{s}$
>   respectively. The radius of the circle where this object is moving is
>   $\textrm{3 meters}$. Find the time which will take the particle to
>   move from $A$ to $B$.

The alternatives given are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&1.57\\
2.&3.14\\
3.&6.28\\
4.&0.16\\
5.&0.31\\
\end{array}$

Typically I would try to show some effort into this. But I'm stuck at the beginning. What is exactly should I do to find the given time.

The only thing which I could come up with is that to find the time can be obtained from the tangential speed as:

$v_{t}=\omega r = \frac{\theta}{t} r$

But apart from this I dont know how to link it with what is being asked. Can somebody give me a hand with this?

With the guidance of Eric Towers I made the following sketch with do help to understand how the vectors are placed in the circle this can aid in the solution of the problem.

[image: Sketch of the vectors in the circle]

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the circle is $3 \,\mathrm{m}$.  The object's speed is always $|(-4,4\sqrt{3})| = |(8,0)| = 8 \,\mathrm{m/s}$.  Now we have a choice.

Recall that, in a circle, tangents (velocities) are perpendicular to radii.  This means the velocity vector $8i$ can only occur at the top or bottom of the circular motion (position angles $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$).  Similarly, the velocity vector $-4i+4\sqrt{3}j$ can only occur at position angles $\pi/6$ or $7\pi/6$.  We can distinguish these because either the circulation is clockwise or it is anticlockwise.

If it is clockwise:  The the velocity vector $8i$ must occur at the top of the circle, at angle $\pi/2$, and the velocity vector $-4i+4\sqrt{3}j$ occurs at angle $7\pi/6$.  So the sphere travels through some number of radians and the length of the portion of the circumference is the radius times the subtended angle.  Then length over speed gets you the time.

If it is anticlockwise:  The velocity vector $8i$ must occur at the bottom of the circle, at position angle $3\pi/2$, and the velocity vector $-4i+4\sqrt{3}j$ must occur at position angle $\pi/6$.  Now the sphere travels half as far, so it takes half the time to do so.

Comment: Okay so you obtained $\left \|  \left \langle -4,4\sqrt 3 \right \rangle\right \|=8$. When you mentioned that the velocity are perpendicular to the circle. Wouldn't it mean that is also occurs at $0$ and $\pi$?. But the part which I'm confused is that if it mentions the vector $\left \langle 8,0 \right \rangle$ this would be in the right side of the circle as it is positive, not in the left side. I don't know how you obtained the angle for the vector $\left \langle -4,4\sqrt{3} \right \rangle$. I guess you can use $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)$ but without calculator?

Comment: I overlooked the fact there's the $30-60$ triangle so it comes from there. But again doing the above operation it would result into $\omega=\frac{\pi}{3}$?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : At position angles $0$ and $\pi$, the velocity is in the $j$ direction.  Whether it's positive or negative depends on whether the motion is clockwise or anticlockwise.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : $\langle -4,4\sqrt{3} \rangle = 8 \langle -1/2, \sqrt{3}/2 \rangle$.  That is, factor out the speed to get a recognizable point on the unit circle.  This point is in quadrant $2$, at angle $2 \pi/3$.

Comment: It seems I overlooked that, I have noticed that as you mentioned it must go in the the top or it could be in the bottom and clock or counterclockwise. But what about the angle of the other vector. Wouldn't it be $\frac{\pi}{3}$?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : The $x$-component of the velocity vector is negative, so the velocity vector is not in quadrant 1.

Comment: Yes I noticed that part. But I'm stuck at where did you obtained $\frac{\pi}{6}$ or $\frac{7\pi}{6}$?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : The position vector has to be perpendicular to the velocity vector, so has to be ahead or behind by $\pi/2$ radians.

Comment: But if it is ahead of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{5\pi}{6}$. Where does it appear the $7$ in the numerator?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : It's.  Not.  $\pi/3$.  $\pi/3$ is in the wrong quadrant.

Comment: Then if is $\frac{2\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{7\pi}{6}$. Is that what you meant?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : $2\pi/3$ is in quadrant 2.  $2\pi/3 + \pi/2$ is in quadrant 3.  Your "$7\pi/3$" would be in quadrant 5, if there were such a thing.  $2/3 + 1/2 = 7/6$.

Comment: I did had a mistake in my calculation. I can understand the logic but it would be of much better aid to have a drawing to understand your answer as I'm stuck of how to visualize the part of behind and after.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : So draw one.  No one is stopping you.  Fully understanding how to make the drawing will very much help you understand what is happening in this problem.  When you realize "someone should put a diagram here" or "someone should summarize this data in a table", you have identified something that your brain recognizes would help your brain process the information.  So do whatever that is.

Comment: I did draw one and put arrows on it but I dont know if this is what you meant by been behind or after the angles you mentioned. Using the angles and the radius I obtained $\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{16}\approx 0.196$.

Comment: But using the other value would result into $\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)\frac{7\pi}{2}=\frac{7\pi}{16}\approx $ 1.37 neither of those appears within the alternatives. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : The problem statement says the radius is $3 \,\mathrm{m}$.  What radius are you describing here?

Comment: The [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector#Arc_length) of the part of a circle subtended by an angle $\theta$ and radius $r$ is $r \theta$.

Comment: I am using that radius, for brevity purposes I omitted the calculation but I simplified the denominator and used $8$ as the speed to find the time.

Comment: To go clockwise from $\pi/2$ to $7\pi/6$, you must revolve through quadrants 1, 4, and 3, stopping at $7\pi/6$.  So the subtended angle is $8\pi/6 = 4 \pi/3$.  I don't see that angle mentioned by you.  I'm becoming very convinced that you have not drawn a diagram, and/or do not understand the difference between clockwise and anticlockwise motion.

Comment: I'm uploading a drawing of how I'm understanding your words so you can see if I did get your idea or not.

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://i.imgur.com/aY9eL4n.png).

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : Why is your diagram not part of your question?  You can edit it in.

Comment: Because of your answer I had to make this drawing as originally I did not had a clear idea of what to do. I will add this drawing. But can you tell me if I did get your idea correctly?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : You correctly have the position vectors for $B$ perpendicular to the velocity vector for $B$.  The velocity vector for $B$ points directly to the right, and the positions you used are $\pi/2$ radians away in each direction (that is at $0 + \pi/2$ and $0 - \pi/2$).  You incorrectly did not do so for $A$.  (continued)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : You currently have two *different* velocity vectors at one point $A$ and neither is the given velocity vector for $A$.  Also, you have put them at the position corresponding to the given velocity vector.  This is incorrect.  Just like $B$, the positions should be $\pi/2$ radians away in each direction.  The velocity vectors for $A$ should point to the upper-left.

Comment: Bear with me, I'm sorry for being slow at this. I'm correcting my drawing to reflect what I did understood from your words.

Comment: I have to be [afk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFK) for several hours.  I'll check back when I'm back online.

Comment: Please take a look into [this](https://i.imgur.com/q3mrEQm.png) Is it correct now?.

Comment: Sorry buddy but i had to redo my drawing after thinking it critically. This new version should be what you meant right?. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/WFf8TMu.png) It checks with what you meant by in one direction travels half of what the other hence it will have half the speed. To me the most important word was "the speed is perpendicular to the radius" that was the lightbulb moment for me.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : Yes, this diagram agrees with the situation described in the problem.

Comment: It took me sometime to ponder what part was wrong but due your guidance I could get to the answer. But I still believe that you could made a drawing of your own for your answer as that would made my understanding easier. But in the end it was worth to made me reason which could had been the right scenario.